# Is it possible to stick when the StickyContainer top is something different than 0?

Tags: react-sticky

I have a fixed navbar, with a height of 50px. I would like to stick when the StickyContainer top is 50, instead of 0. Please how can I acheive that ?

Answer (score 0):

I got it,

```
<StickyContainer>
  <Sticky topOffset={-50}>
    ({style, isSticky}) => (
      <div style={{ ...style, paddingTop: isSticky ? '50px' : '0px' }}>
        ...
      </div>
    )
  </Sticky>
</StickyContainer>
```