# React-sticky: how to correctly provide distanceFromTop option

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-sticky

The [example](https://github.com/captivationsoftware/react-sticky#full-example) says that I should provide it with this way:

```
<Sticky>
  {({
     style,
     isSticky,
     wasSticky,
     distanceFromTop,
     distanceFromBottom,
     calculatedHeight
   }) => (
     <header style={style}>
       {/* ... */}
        </header>
      )}
</Sticky>
{/* ... */}
```

But how can I correctly define `distanceFromTop` and provide it to the sticky component and apply it? Could anybody provide an example please?

Answer (score 1):

One nicer way is to handle this sticky container when you have sticky navigation.

```
<StickyContainer >
   <Sticky topOffset={-navHeight}>
       {({ style, isSticky }) =>
         <div style={{...style, top: `${navHeight + style.top}px`}} />
        }
   </Sticky>
 </StickyContainer>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not find a way to make *distanceFromTop* work, but found a way to get the desired effect by using *isSticky*.

```
      <StickyContainer >
        <Sticky topOffset={-20}>
          {({ style, isSticky }) =>
            <div style={{...style, marginTop: isSticky ? '20px' : '0px'}} />
          }
        </Sticky>
      </StickyContainer>
```

This will place the div tag 20px from the top.

**acmoune** gave the answer in this post:
[Is it possible to stick when the StickyContainer top is something different than 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48736693/is-it-possible-to-stick-when-the-stickycontainer-top-is-something-different-than)

Answer (score 0):

"distanceFromTop" is a read-only value. It can't be modified.
It is the number of pixels, the Sticky container has crossed from the top.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).